# Swift Array causing indexing issues in Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, dictionary

For my app, I've created a Struct to store team names, and font values.

The array 'teams' contains a dictionary of 20 different entries.

Example code

```
struct TeamInfoLibrary {
var teams = [
    [
        "name": "Arsenal",
        "stadiumImage": "",
        "teamColor": ["red": 239, "green": 1, "blue": 7, "alpha": 1.0],
        "fontColor": ["red": 255, "green": 255, "blue": 255, "alpha": 1.0]
    ],
    [
        "name": "Aston Villa",
        "stadiumImage": "",
        "teamColor": ["red": 148, "green": 190, "blue": 229, "alpha": 1.0],
        "fontColor": ["red": 122, "green": 0, "blue": 60, "alpha": 1.0]
    ],

/// Plus 18 more entries 

] ///close dictionary

}
```

Once the array gets over 3/4 dictionary entries, Xcode seems to be indexing indefinitely and will not let me build the project. There are no errors, it simply seems to freeze and be forever stuck indexing the project.

Any help would be appreciated. Looking here there are a few suggestions that it could be a bug in Xcode, but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift is having difficulty inferring the type of your structure.  Give it some help by giving it a type:

```
var teams: [[String:AnyObject]] = [
    [
        "name": "Arsenal",
        "stadiumImage": "",
        "teamColor": ["red": 239, "green": 1, "blue": 7, "alpha": 1.0],
        "fontColor": ["red": 255, "green": 255, "blue": 255, "alpha": 1.0]
    ],
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks - that resolved the issue and I was able to build straight away after a clean