# Swift Array of Ranges causing issues

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I am trying to implement an array that contains multiple arrays of Integers (well, LOTS of Integers) like this...

```
let arrayOfRanges = [Array(0 ... 299), Array(300 ... 399), Array(400 ... 699), Array(700 ... 799), Array(800 ... 899), Array(900 ... 1199)]
```

but every time I type it into Xcode, Xcode hangs on indexing. I've searched and found a few older cases of people with a similar problem with Arrays and it seems to be related to Xcode having difficult inferring the type. [Swift Array causing indexing issues in Xcode 6.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411298/swift-array-causing-indexing-issues-in-xcode-6-1-1) Does anybody have any ideas as to how I can better code this? I would like...

```
//Sets magicNumber to the Int 411
let arrayOfRanges = [Array(0 ... 299), Array(300 ... 399), Array(400 ... 699), Array(700 ... 799), Array(800 ... 899), Array(900 ... 1199)]
magicNumber = arrayOfRanges[2][11]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No issues in Xcode 7.2.1. Your code is running perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variable as an array of arrays of Int

```
let arrayOfRanges: [[Int]] = [Array(0 ... 299), Array(300 ... 399), Array(400 ... 699), Array(700 ... 799), Array(800 ... 899), Array(900 ... 1199)]
let magicNumber = arrayOfRanges[2][11]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. Now that I look at it I feel really dumb for not seeing this before..lol

Comment: Nah, it's part of learning. I've asked simple questions that baffled me because the answer just didn't pop into my head. Accept the answer if you like it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t anything wrong with the posted code except that you haven’t defined `magicNumber`. Also

```
magicNumber = arrayOfRanges[2][11]
```

will be `411` and not `410`. Refer to the attached screenshot from playground.[image]

Comment: oops...lol...edited to say 411